# Are there batteries with separated charging and discharging ports?

Tags: batteries

Are there commercial energy storage systems with such characteristics? Or, any reference guide on how to design such a system? Really appreciated.

Comment: Flow batteries? Otherwise, no - because it's a chemically symmetrical system and the battery is *either* charging *or* discharging.

Comment: Yes, flow batteries. Are there battery systems in which while some storage units are being charged through port A, another cell is being discharged through port B? The application would be on solar energy harvesting.

Comment: @Juan What is the purpose of charging and discharging the batteries if the energy being produced is required right now?

Comment: That's a terrible reason for a design constraint. I'm not sure it even makes sense; surely Ibatt = Ipanels - Iload where Ibatt can be positive or negative?

Answer (score 2):

Batteries don't have separate charge/discharge ports, power management units have. Either the PMU receives more energy than needed, and uses that excess to charge the battery, or it receives not enough and compensates the deficit by discharging the battery. Charging and discharging at the same time makes little sense.

For example, here's the data sheet of [AXP209](http://dl.linux-sunxi.org/AXP/AXP209_Datasheet_v1.0en.pdf) PMU which some mobile phones and battery-powered computers use. It can manage power 3 inputs, 2 batteries (one rechargeable and one non-rechargeable) and provides a programmable set of output voltages via 2 step-down converters and 5 LDOs. The block diagram inside the datasheet should be a good start if you want to design a similar system.

Answer (score 0):

It is extremely common to connect a charging source, a rechargable battery, and a load in parallel, with no extra components, or extra terminals on the battery - every conventionally-powered car on the road is wired this way.

In a car, if the alternator is producing more power than required by the loads, the excess power charges the battery.  If the alternator is producing less power than the load requires, the battery will discharge to provide the additional power required by the load.  The switching between charging and discharging happens automagically as power requirements vary.